# Js: getElementById

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of image like this:

```
<div id="imgSorce">
    <a href="#"><img src="images/img1.png"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img src='images/img2.png'/></a>
</div>
<div id="imgResult"></div>
```

I want to be able to insert the images to a div tag when I click on any of them.

```
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("imgResult").innerHTML = "<img src='images/aftersurprise.png' />";
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You want to copy the `img` thats in the clicked `a` element to the `div`?

Comment: <a href="javascript:myFunction()"><img src="images/img1.png"/></a>

Comment: Yes Rory! That is what I want to achieve

Comment: you mean that when you are clicking your image in the "imgSorce" the image that was clicked need to go to the imgResult?
Should it be duplicated or to move to there ?

Comment: Hi Bitton, It should be copied or attached to imgResult!

Comment: Posted you a snippet with plain javascript. works great. :)

Answer (score 0):

As you tag with jquery, you can do like below:

1. Find the `<img>` inside the clicked `<a>`. It's `$(this).children('img')`
2. Clone it. It's `.clone()`
3. Before move the picture to `#imgResult`, clear anything inside it. 
   `$('#imgResult').empty()`

Edited: If image needs to stay, don't do the step 3, which means replace
`$('#imageResult').empty()` to simple `$('#imageResult')`

4. Put the cloned image to `#imageResult`. It's `.appendTo($('#imgResult'))`

```js
$('a').click(function() {
   $(this).children('img').clone().appendTo($('#imgResult'));
});
```

```css
img {
max-width: 300px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="imgSorce">
    <a href="#"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/cWCw1q2.jpg"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img src='https://i.imgur.com/4EiQldb.jpg'/></a>
</div>
<div id="imgResult"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way I can add multiple images to the div retaining the previous.

Comment: So you want to keep all clicked record?

Comment: Yes! I want to keep all clicked record

Comment: Question Answered! Thanks fuyushimoya

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with jQuery:

```
jQuery('a').on('click', function(){
    var pic = jQuery(this).html();
    jQuery('#imgResult').html(pic);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1o4ngjnc/

Comment: Is there a way I can persist the image on clicking on it the second time! Thnaks

Answer (score 0):

Try like this by using `onClick`.

```js
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("imgResult").innerHTML = "<img src='images/aftersurprise.png' />";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="imgSorce">
    <a href="#" onClick="myFunction()"><img src="images/img1.png"/></a>
    <a href="#"onClick="myFunction()"><img src='images/img2.png'/></a>
</div>
<div id="imgResult"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction(elment) {

    
    
    // Copy the <li> element and its child nodes
    var cln = elment.firstChild.cloneNode(true);
    
    // Append the cloned <li> element to <ul> with id="myList1"
    document.getElementById("imgResult").appendChild(cln);
}
```

```html
<div id="imgSorce">
    <a href="#" onclick="myFunction(this)"><img width='100px' height='100px' src="http://www.hdwallpapersimages.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Winter-Tiger-Wild-Cat-Images.jpg"/></a>
    <a href="#" onclick="myFunction(this)"><img width='100px' height='100px' src='http://www.hdwallpapersimages.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Winter-Tiger-Wild-Cat-Images.jpg'/></a>
</div>
<div id="imgResult"></div>
```

Comment: Question Answered! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code in pure Javascript:

```js
function myFunction(clicked_id) {
  document.getElementById("imgResult").innerHTML = "<img src='" + document.getElementById(clicked_id).getAttribute("src") + "'/>"
}
```

```html
<div id="imgSorce">
  <a href="#" ><img onclick="myFunction(this.id)" id="img1" src="http://placekitten.com.s3.amazonaws.com/homepage-samples/96/140.jpg"/></a>
  <a href="#" ><img onclick="myFunction(this.id)" id="img2" src="http://placekitten.com.s3.amazonaws.com/homepage-samples/96/139.jpg"/></a>
</div>
<div id="imgResult"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may simply replace the `innerHTML`:

```js
function myFunction(el) {
  document.getElementById("imgResult").innerHTML = el.innerHTML;
  //in case you want to keep appending images insted of replacing the old one, use `+=`
  //document.getElementById("imgResult").innerHTML += el.innerHTML
}
```

```html
<div id="imgSorce">
  <a onclick="myFunction(this);" href="#">
    <img src="images/img1.png" />
  </a>
  <a onclick="myFunction(this);" href="#">
    <img src='images/img2.png' />
  </a>
</div>
<div id="imgResult"></div>
```